# Why can't I see my public adress when typing `ip a`

Tags: networking, server

I am running locally [Firefox Send](https://github.com/mozilla/send) to share files my friends.

When I access url that firefox send give me: http://0.0.0.0:8081/download/8e9c648c27f19643/#9cT19OUTM3-68caDmHMl6A

I can access download page, but when replace the `0.0.0.0` local ip with public IP given in : https://www.whatismyip.com it timesout.

Also, when typing `ip a | grep inet` I don't see the public ip.

How can I enable it ?

Comment: Might just be easier to go to http://ipchicken.com to find it externally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to allow port forwarding on the router/modem that connects your device to the internet.

For this you will need the management IP of the router/modem and administrator access. How to forward ports will vary depending on the manafacturer.